# Fixing a raster with unknown spatial reference so other rasters show up

Tags: raster, arcmap, georeferencing

I am trying to create a dataset with data from different raster datasets in ArcMap. One of the raster datasets seems to have an "unknown spatial reference", and it shows "unknown" as XY coordinate system.

[image]

I tried assigning it a coordinate system, which didn't work for reasons that might be obvious to others. When I try to import a raster that does not have such problems together with the unreferenced one, it is listed in the Table of Contents but it does not show up as a map.

What exactly is wrong here, and how can I fix the raster with the unknown spatial reference?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Turns out the raster I want to use is projected in the Swiss coordinate system (anchored arbitrarily at 600000m, 200000m in Bern). The other rasters I tried to import were in Mercator coordinates, which also uses metric coordinates, so it did in fact show these new layers -- I simply never zoomed out far enough to make them visible.